# Social Media and email extraction code needs updating

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit stuck on this code that I put together. I took two codes and put them together, although this code does work for the most part there are still some issues that I can not fix.

**WHAT THE CODE DOES**

Opens a urls in Sheet3 column A, extracts the emails from the site and any social media links. Then puts the results from column B onwards

[image]

**Problems**

**1)** TWO code have been put together, but can it be written smarter as currently it looks for emails first and then it looks for social media urls, so if there was 100 urls, it would look for emails in them first and then GO BACK and look for social media urls again, hence the 100 are processed 200 times. When it should find emails and social media urls AT THE SAME TIME

**2)** Browser has been set to false but still shows in TASK BAR

[image]

**3)** When the process is finished a userform called, "Complete" should show. but it does NOT.

**4)** As the browser would show, I had to put some code at the end to close the browser, but it is not closing the browser. idealy I would not want the browser to show.

**5)** Both IE and "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" are used. As I stated this was TWO code that I put together and therefore not the best. I think "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" would be much faster. However I could not change the first half of the code to only use "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0" as I have always used IE in the past. Please could someone advise of what to do

**What I have tried so far.**

I have tried to place the code in several variations, non worked. I was able to fix the part where the active sheet did not have to be sheet3. So it does not matter what sheet I am on it will GET and Paste the results into sheet3.

```
Private Sub SocialEmailStartBut_Click()
''Extract emails only from urls
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim url As String
Dim x As Long
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim Worksheet As Sheet3
Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = False '###### set to false BUT shows in task bar #####

x = 2 '''start row
Do While Sheet3.Cells(x, 1) <> ""
    url = Sheet3.Cells(x, 1)

ie.navigate url
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTML = ie.document
    Set ElementCol = HTML.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In ElementCol
    If InStr(link, "mailto:") Then
        Sheet3.Cells(x, 2).Value = link
        Sheet3.Cells(x, 2) = Right(link, Len(link) - InStr(link, ":"))
        Sheet3.Cells(x, 2).Columns.AutoFit
    End If
Next
x = x + 1
Loop

'#################################################################
'###################Social URL Extractor##########################
'#################################################################
Dim counter As Long
Dim website As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim continue As Boolean
Dim respHead As String

''''The row where website addresses start
row = 2
    continue = True

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    Do While continue
'''Could set this to first cell with URL then OFFSET columns to get next web site
Set website = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & row)
        If Len(website.Value) < 1 Then
            continue = False
        Exit Sub
        End If

        If website Is Nothing Then
            continue = False
        End If

'''Debug.Print website
    With http
        On Error Resume Next
        .Open "GET", website.Value, False
        .send

'''If the website sent a valid response to our request, URLS ARE IN COLUMN A
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If .Status = 200 Then
            HTML.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
                Set links = HTML.getElementsByTagName("a")
'''COLUMN C = FACEBOOK
   For Each link In links
      If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "FACEBOOK") Then
      website.Offset(0, 2).Value = link.href
   End If
'''COLUMN D = INSTAGRAM
    If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "INSTAGRAM") Then
        website.Offset(0, 3).Value = link.href
    End If
'''COLUMN E = TWITTER
    If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "TWITTER") Then
        website.Offset(0, 4).Value = link.href
    End If
'''COLUMN F = YOUTUBE
    If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "YOUTUBE") Then
        website.Offset(0, 5).Value = link.href
    End If
'''COLUMN G = LinkedIn
    If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "LINKEDIN") Then
        website.Offset(0, 6).Value = link.href
    End If
Next
    End If
    Set website = Nothing
Else
'''Debug.Print "Error loading page IN COLUMN H"
    website.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Error with website address"
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
 End With
row = row + 1
Loop

Complete.Show '#### THIS FORM DOES NOT SHOW AT THE END ####
''' CLOSE BROWSER
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
Set ElementCol = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't email harvesting illegal?

Comment: No and Yes, depends on your country most nations are fine with it. I think Australia has the toughest rules, were it can be illegal. Sending out SPAM emails are illegal in almost all nations. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email-address_harvesting)[link]

Comment: **First:** If there is more than one email address or more than one social media link from a service on a website, your macro will write them all to the table. However, only the last found one is kept, because every found address is written into the same cell. So you should first rethink your table structure. **Second:** If there are pages with dynamic content, MSXML2 may not find all the content you are looking for. With so many different URLs I would stick with IE. **Third:** Don't use `Complete.Show`. Use `MsgBox "Ready"` instead.

Comment: Zwenn, thanks for your reply. **Firstly:** I will stick with IE if you are saying that is best, it just seemed a bit slower. **Secondly:** I am aware of the email address being over written, however I could not work out how to change the code, so in the end i left it as it was as I am limited in my VBA skills. **Third:**  Orginaly a message box would popup, however I changed it to a userform, which I was using for another code. I works fine for that code but not for this and I can not work out why. **Forth:** Any idea WHY the IE is showing when it has been set to "FALSE" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in thinking. To load dynamic content when the server reports that the page has loaded, another pause is necessary. So you would have to pause at every page because you can't check that. Anyway, I don't know how. So now I have implemented it with the faster MSXML2.

I added counters for all found links. If more than one link was found, a comment with the found count is set in the cell. If you go through the same URLs again, the comments and found links will be deleted and if necessary reset.

The counters should give you an overview if you need a different table layout to get all links and not only the last one. In this case you need your own table to enter all links.

Try the following macro. Read the comments carefully.

```
Sub ScrapeSoMeAndMailAddresses()

'******************************************************
'The macro works on the sheet from which it was started
'******************************************************

Dim url As String
Dim http As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeAllLinks As Object
Dim nodeOneLink As Object
Dim currentRow As Long

'Counters to check, if there are more than one address per page
Dim addressCounters(5) As Long
Dim checkCounters As Long

  'Initialize variables
  currentRow = 2
  Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  
  'Loop over all URLs in column A in the active table
  Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value <> ""
    'Scroll if current row > 14
    If currentRow > 14 Then
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
    End If
    'Clear content in current row
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(currentRow, 2), Cells(currentRow, 9)).ClearContents
    'Get next url from table
    url = ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
    'Load page
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send
    'Check if page loading was successful
    If http.Status = 200 Then
      'Build html document for DOM operations
      htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
      'Create node list from all links of the page
      Set nodeAllLinks = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
      'Walk through all links of the node list
      For Each nodeOneLink In nodeAllLinks
        'Check for mail address
        If InStr(1, nodeOneLink.href, "mailto:") Then
          'Write mail address to table in column B
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = Right(nodeOneLink.href, Len(nodeOneLink.href) - InStr(nodeOneLink.href, ":"))
          'Increment mail address counter
          addressCounters(0) = addressCounters(0) + 1
        End If
        'Check for Facebook address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "FACEBOOK") Then
          'Write Facebook address to table in column C
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Increment Facebook counter
          addressCounters(1) = addressCounters(1) + 1
        End If
        'Check for Instagram address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "INSTAGRAM") Then
          'Write INSTAGRAM address to table in column D
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Increment Instagram counter
          addressCounters(2) = addressCounters(2) + 1
        End If
        'Check for Twitter address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "TWITTER") Then
          'Write Twitter address to table in column E
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 5).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Increment Twitter counter
          addressCounters(3) = addressCounters(3) + 1
        End If
        'Check for YouTube address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "YOUTUBE") Then
          'Write YouTube address to table in column F
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 6).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Increment YouTube counter
          addressCounters(4) = addressCounters(4) + 1
        End If
        'Check for LinkedIn address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "LINKEDIN") Then
          'Write LinkedIn address to table in column G
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 7).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Increment LinkedIn counter
          addressCounters(5) = addressCounters(5) + 1
        End If
      Next nodeOneLink
      
      'Check counters
      For checkCounters = 0 To 5
        'Delete comment if there is one
        If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, checkCounters + 2).Comment Is Nothing Then
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, checkCounters + 2).Comment.Delete
        End If
        'Set comment if more than 1 link were found
        If addressCounters(checkCounters) > 1 Then
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, checkCounters + 2).AddComment Text:=CStr(addressCounters(checkCounters))
          ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, checkCounters + 2).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        End If
      Next checkCounters
    Else
      'Page not loaded
      'Write message in column H
      ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 9).Value = "Error with website address"
    End If
    
    'Prepare for next page
    Erase addressCounters
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Loop
  
  'Clean up
  Set http = Nothing
  Set htmlDoc = Nothing
  Set nodeAllLinks = Nothing
  Set nodeOneLink = Nothing
  
  'Check if this works now
  Complete.Show
End Sub
```

## Edit: Revised code

Since the macro above is more or less a proof of concept, I have now developed a version that meets the requirements of the first comment under this posting. Nothing more to read from the pages, but a lot of work ;-)

You have to create another table which contains all addresses after a macro run. You have to create the headline manually once. I have **not** implemented a check for duplicate addresses!

The code of the macro is not perfect (all in one, no functions), but it is much more flexible than version 1. If you understand the code, it should be quite easy to integrate additional platforms if needed.

About the thing with `Sheet3`:
You can access a sheet from VBA either by the name it has on the tab in the normal Excel view or by its index. `Sheet3` is the name as far as I understood it. At the top of the *Initialize Variables* part, you can easily change the two default names `Sheet3` and `Sheet4` to match the names used on the tabs. You don't have to change anything else.

If you start the macro the content in both sheets will be delete at first.

**Please read the comments in the VBA code carefully!**

```
Sub ScrapeSoMeAndMailAddresses()

'Columns for both tables
Const colUrl As Long = 1 'Must always be the first column
Const colMail As Long = 2 'Must always be the first column before SoMe platforms
Const colFacebook As Long = 3
Const colInstagram As Long = 4
Const colTwitter As Long = 5
Const colYouTube As Long = 6
Const colLinkedIn As Long = 7 'Must always be the last column of SoMe platforms
Const colError As Long = 9 'Must always be the last column

Dim url As String
Dim http As Object
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nodeAllLinks As Object
Dim nodeOneLink As Object
Dim pageLoadSuccessful As Boolean
Dim tableUrlsOneAddressLeft As String
Dim tableAllAddresses As String
Dim currentRowTableUrls As Long
Dim lastRowTableUrls As Long
Dim currentRowsTableAll(colUrl To colLinkedIn) As Long
Dim lastRowTableAll As Long
Dim addressCounters(colMail To colLinkedIn) As Long
Dim checkCounters As Long

  'Initialize variables
  tableUrlsOneAddressLeft = "Sheet3"
  currentRowTableUrls = 2 'First row for content
  tableAllAddresses = "Sheet4"
  For checkCounters = colUrl To colLinkedIn
    currentRowsTableAll(checkCounters) = 2 'First rows for content
  Next checkCounters
  Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  
  'Clear all contents and comments in the URL source sheet from email column to error column
  lastRowTableUrls = Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(Rows.count, colUrl).End(xlUp).row
  Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Range(Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail), Cells(lastRowTableUrls, colError)).ClearContents
  Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Range(Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail), Cells(lastRowTableUrls, colError)).ClearComments
  
  'Delete all rows except headline in the sheet with all addresses
  lastRowTableAll = Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(Rows.count, colUrl).End(xlUp).row
  Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Rows(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) & ":" & lastRowTableAll).Delete Shift:=xlUp
  
  'Loop over all URLs in column A in the URL source sheet
  Do While Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, 1).Value <> ""
    
    '**************************************
    'Scroll for visual monitoring
    'Comment out the following three lines,
    'if Sheet3 is not visible while the
    'macro runs
    'Otherwise a runtime error will occur
    If currentRowTableUrls > 14 Then
      ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
    End If
    '**************************************
    
    'Get next url from the URL source sheet
    url = Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colUrl).Value
    
    'Try to load page
    'Temporarily disable error
    'handling if there is a timeout
    On Error Resume Next
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Check if page loading was successful
    If http.Status = 200 Then
      pageLoadSuccessful = True
    End If
    
    If pageLoadSuccessful Then
      'Build html document for DOM operations
      htmlDoc.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
      'Create node list from all links of the page
      Set nodeAllLinks = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
      'Walk through all links of the node list
      For Each nodeOneLink In nodeAllLinks
        'Check for mail address
        If InStr(1, nodeOneLink.href, "mailto:") Then
          'Write mail address to both tables
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail).Value = Right(nodeOneLink.href, Len(nodeOneLink.href) - InStr(nodeOneLink.href, ":"))
          Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colMail), colMail).Value = Right(nodeOneLink.href, Len(nodeOneLink.href) - InStr(nodeOneLink.href, ":"))
          'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
          If currentRowsTableAll(colMail) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
            'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
            Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
            'Increment url counter
            currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
          End If
          'Increment mail counters
          currentRowsTableAll(colMail) = currentRowsTableAll(colMail) + 1
          addressCounters(colMail) = addressCounters(colMail) + 1
        End If
        'Check for Facebook address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "FACEBOOK") Then
          'Write Facebook address to both tables
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colFacebook).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook), colFacebook).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
          If currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
            'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
            Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
            'Increment url counter
            currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
          End If
          'Increment Facebook counters
          currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook) = currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook) + 1
          addressCounters(colFacebook) = addressCounters(colFacebook) + 1
        End If
        'Check for Instagram address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "INSTAGRAM") Then
          'Write INSTAGRAM address to both tables
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colInstagram).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colInstagram), colInstagram).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
          If currentRowsTableAll(colInstagram) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
            'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
            Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
            'Increment url counter
            currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
          End If
          'Increment Instagram counters
          currentRowsTableAll(colInstagram) = currentRowsTableAll(colInstagram) + 1
          addressCounters(colInstagram) = addressCounters(colInstagram) + 1
        End If
        'Check for Twitter address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "TWITTER") Then
          'Write Twitter address to both tables
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colTwitter).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colTwitter), colTwitter).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
          If currentRowsTableAll(colTwitter) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
            'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
            Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
            'Increment url counter
            currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
          End If
          'Increment Twitter counters
          currentRowsTableAll(colTwitter) = currentRowsTableAll(colTwitter) + 1
          addressCounters(colTwitter) = addressCounters(colTwitter) + 1
        End If
        'Check for YouTube address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "YOUTUBE") Then
          'Write YouTube address to both tables
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colYouTube).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colYouTube), colYouTube).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
          If currentRowsTableAll(colYouTube) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
            'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
            Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
            'Increment url counter
            currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
          End If
          'Increment YouTube counters
          currentRowsTableAll(colYouTube) = currentRowsTableAll(colYouTube) + 1
          addressCounters(colYouTube) = addressCounters(colYouTube) + 1
        End If
        'Check for LinkedIn address
        If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "LINKEDIN") Then
          'Write LinkedIn address to both tables
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colLinkedIn).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colLinkedIn), colLinkedIn).Value = nodeOneLink.href
          'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
          If currentRowsTableAll(colLinkedIn) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
            'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
            Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
            'Increment url counter
            currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
          End If
          'Increment LinkedIn counters
          currentRowsTableAll(colLinkedIn) = currentRowsTableAll(colLinkedIn) + 1
          addressCounters(colLinkedIn) = addressCounters(colLinkedIn) + 1
        End If
      Next nodeOneLink
      
      'Check address counters
      For checkCounters = colMail To colLinkedIn
        'Set comment if more than 1 link were found
        If addressCounters(checkCounters) > 1 Then
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, checkCounters).AddComment Text:=CStr(addressCounters(checkCounters))
          Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, checkCounters).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        End If
      Next checkCounters
    Else
      'Page not loaded
      'Write message URL table
      Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colError).Value = "Error with URL or timeout"
    End If
    
    'Prepare for next page
    pageLoadSuccessful = False
    Erase addressCounters
    lastRowTableAll = Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(Rows.count, colUrl).End(xlUp).row
    For checkCounters = colUrl To colLinkedIn
      currentRowsTableAll(checkCounters) = lastRowTableAll + 1 'First rows for next page content
    Next checkCounters
    currentRowTableUrls = currentRowTableUrls + 1
  Loop
  
  'Clean up
  Set http = Nothing
  Set htmlDoc = Nothing
  Set nodeAllLinks = Nothing
  Set nodeOneLink = Nothing
  
  'Check if this works now
  Complete.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Zwenn **Firstly:** This is super a real gem, I only have two issue. I used `Set website = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & row)` so sheet3 was set as the URL sheet & where data is pasted. You changed it to active sheet. How hard is it to change back to Sheet3. See my original post **What I have tried so far.** I changed it so it would do this. ***Secondly** The cell counter is super but for 1 link it shows 62 email & only keeps 1 email. Is there a way to get all the emails, **OR** have URLS on sheet4 and results in 3 so it only goes to next urls when no more emails are found

Comment: **Zwenn** I have got the currunt row part working now, this is  fine. I am just not sure on these two bit `ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(currentRow, 2), Cells(currentRow, 9)).ClearContents` & `currentRow = currentRow + 1` as these refer to current row, the first one is to active sheet. I tried **Sheet3.Range** but it did not work so I have for now comment these two out. **IF POSSIBLE** If this could pull **ALL** the emails from a url that would be super. if that is too much of an ask, then its fine as you have already done a super job.

Comment: @Sharid I'm in the process of working out something more advanced for you. Please be patient :-)

Comment: @Sharid I have extended my answer with a new version

Comment: Zwenn, Firstly thank you very much this is super and way out of my depth. This does what I am after. The sheets were called Sheet 3 and 4 I just changed the order of the sheets in the code as you stated this would be possible. I have being trying to runs this from a command buttons on a user form, but can't get it to work as **Sheet4 which will have the urls pasted into**, will **NOT** be the active sheet nor will sheet 3. The results will show in TWO listboxes on a useform **Therefore** I could be on any sheet 1 to 10 and I need the code to still work. This is the ONLY bit I am stuck on.

Comment: @Sharid Have you commented out the part with `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1`?

Comment: Yes, your note state this. I did it from the start of the IF to the end as you notes state 3 lines. The error happens before this on BOTH OF these line. (To clear the sheets)   `Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Range(Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail), Cells(lastRowTableUrls, colError)).ClearContents` **ERROR MESSAGE** Runtime error 1004 Application defined or object defined error. It then works it way down. **Also** if it can not open a url as the link is dead then it gives an error here `If http.Status = 200 Then`. its also not pulling off all emails. Sorry to be such a pain. Thanks

Comment: @Sharid All ok I'am curious. But I can't reproduce the mistakes. Is there a way to send me the file with the URLs? Mail to zwenn_gluecksplilz[at]gmx.de if possible.

Comment: Email sent to you today, but it is stating address not found, i did change it to @ sight and no brackets

Comment: You can sent an email here as I use it for Junk mail. I can then reply to you direct from my personal emails private.post.1@googlemail.com